# Function for calculating maximum value of limited width number

Tags: c#, .net, math, encoding

For example to calculate the maximum value of a 3 character long base26 encoding the expression would be `(((26 * 26) + 26) * 26) + 26)`, but if I simply wanted to calculate the amount of permutations of the same length with a zero-based numeral system then I could use the Pow method in the Math class like `Math.Pow(26, 3)`. Is there any method in the Math class to do the prior?

For anyone's interest, here is my encoding method for Base26:

```
    public static string ToBase26(uint u)
    {
        char[] cx = new char[7];
        int index = 0;

        while (u > 0)
        {
            u--;
            cx[index++] = (char)(65 + (u % 26));
            u /= 26;
        }

        Array.Resize(ref cx, index);
        Array.Reverse(cx);

        return new string(cx);
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by a "numerical system"? All built-in numerical types have MaxValue field, if that's what you're talking about.

Comment: I mean an alternative numeral system such as base26 or hexadecimal (base16).

Comment: Ah, so by the "character" here you mean a digit in that custom numerical encoding?

Comment: Yes exactly, in this example a character part of string with a limited length of 3.

Comment: Just why do you have `(26 + (26 * 26) + (26 * 26))` (it gives `1378`)? What does it represent? It is not related to `Pow(26, 3) - 1` which is the same as `25*Pow(26,2) + 25*Pow(26,1) + 25*Pow(26,0)`, is it?

Comment: Your ToBase26 method is wrong, you're forgetting zero.

Comment: What is the use of the `u--` statement in the loop? What happens if the given argument is `u=0`?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen That number represents nothing because I made a mistake. The correct sum is `(((26 * 26) + 26) * 26) + 26`, convert that number to base26 and the result will be ZZZ

Comment: @Luaan Base26 doesn't support zero by design.

Comment: @LutzL In that case the result will equal String.Empty because there is no positive value to convert.

Comment: Then please give the encoding for the numbers 26, 27, 28 in that design.

Comment: @LutzL A-Z as you may see in the example. 27 and 28 are not valid as this is base26.

Comment: Your aim seems to be to mirror the axis labeling of spreadsheet tables, where 1..26 corresponds to A..Z, then 27 to 53 to AA..AZ etc. You should formulate your problem accordingly. And then indeed your formula for the number of encodings with up to 3 digits, 26+26^2+26^3 = 26*(26^3-1)/25, is correct

Comment: @LutzL Yes that is what I'm using base26 for, but eitherway the characterset isn't relevant.

Comment: @toplel32 No, that's what I'm trying to tell you. That's not base-26. Base-26 would be 0 = A, 26 = BA. You're calling it Base-26, but it isn't base 26. That's why Matthew's answer doesn't work for you - his code gives you the solution for base-26, but that's not what you're doing here.

Comment: @Luaan Base26 means that there are 26 possible variations per place, the possibility of zero (as we are used to in our numeral system) is no requirement. But I understand the confusion.

Comment: @toplel32 Not really. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexavigesimal for more information on base 26. The number has to be in the format of `a * base^0 + b * base^1 + c * base^2 + ...`. It's called a "positional system". For example, roman numerals are not a positional system, and you can't call it base 7 just because it uses 7 different letters. This is mathematics, not computer science.

Comment: @Luaan I'm happy you learned something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using letter combinations of up to n letters to label something, like columns in a spreadsheet table, will indeed give

```
26+26^2+26+3+...+26^n
```

different labels. The compact formula is the geometric sum

```
26*(26^n-1)/25
```

---

Each block of exactly k letters can be interpreted as the numbers 0 to 26^k-1 in base-26 in a zero-padded format. Using the letters 0,1,2,3, the 3 letter block would look like

```
000, 001, 002, 003, 010, ..., 033, 100, ..., 333
```

the corresponding encoding using letters A,B,C,D would be

```
AAA, AAB, AAC, AAD, ABA, ..., ADD, BAA, ..., DDD
```

Comment: I still don't understand... For n == 3, `26*(26^3-1)/25` gives 18279, but given the letters A..Z then the total number of possible combinations is 26^3 = 17575...

Comment: You have to add the number of two-letter and one-letter labels.

Comment: Ahh ok, so there's no normal base involved here at all. I was thrown by the mention of the Base 26 encoding in the OP.

Comment: Ah, OK, so just to sum up: In a "standard" base 10 example, the number `007` would be the same as just `7`. That would be `pow(10,k)` different values, running from `0` to `999...9` where the last number is `pow(10,k) - 1`. In the "non-standard" base 10, we count `0,1,2,...,8,9,00,01,02,...,98,99,000,001,002,...,998,999,0000,...`. Here we get `10*(pow(10,k)-1)/(10-1)` according to your formula. It still goes from `0` to `999...9`, but there are more combinations since for example `007` is distinct from (and much later than) `7`.

Comment: Yes, exactly that and especially the last observation.